# Specified cast is not valid while accessing column value

Tags: c#, datatable

I am finding records in datatable. If the record matches then I want to compare value in the datarow and do some operation. Please see my code below for better explanation,

```
        foreach (DataRow row2  in dtTo.Rows)
        {

            DataRow[] match = dtReturn.Select("Id = " + row2["Id"]);

            if (match.Length > 0)
            {
                if (match[0]["boolInt"] == 1) // Getting error on this line
                {
                    match[0]["NewValues"] = "";
                }

            }

        }
```

I was getting error on below line

```
 if (match[0]["boolInt"] == 1)
```

Then resharper suggested me to cast to bool. so I changed above line to

```
 if( (bool) (match[0]["bClosed"] = 1))
```

But when I run the project I get run time error as "Specified cast is not valid" on above line.
In immediate window I get value as 1 when I type ,

```
(match[0]["bClosed"]
```

What should i do to get rid of this error?

Comment: What is the real CLR type of ["boolInt"] field? Could this field store nulls?

Comment: @Dennis No there wont be null. The field is tinyint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this:

> No there wont be null. The field is tinyint

you code should look like this (AFAIR, `tinyint` in SQL server matches `byte` in CLR):

```
if ((byte)(match[0]["boolInt"]) == 1)
{
}
```

If you know the field type, there's no need to call `Convert` methods. The faster way is to cast directly to that known type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the value to int. You can do it like this:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(match[0]["boolInt"]) == 1)
```

But if the column contains a value that can't be casted you wil get an error.

A better aproach would be:

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(match[0]["boolInt"], out number);
if (result && number == 1)
```

Comment: This isn't a better approach. This is a slower approach.

Comment: This is better since it is safer. If the value can't be casted the first approach would cause an exception and he would have to handle everything in a catch block. In the end it's a question of design.

Comment: Do you really think, that OP receives his data from abstract source, and knows nothing about field type? `Convert` type and `TryParse` methods are useful, when you're not sure about data type.

Comment: I know what you mean. And the "better" is only applicable to my first solution. So why don't you post your solution?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé: "So why don't you post your solution?" - because I've asked OP about the field type. :)

Comment: @Dennis: And apparently he doesn't know. I hope this tells you something. Now please post a better solution or stop this.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé: "And apparently he doesn't know" - of course, he knows. See his comment above. :)

Comment: @Dennis: Checkmate. You win ;-). Have a nice day

Comment: @RomanoZumbé sorry i accepted Dennis answer as i didnt had to cast. Really sorry but many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if ((match[0]["boolInt"] as int?) == 1)
 {
     match[0]["NewValues"] = "";
 }
```

if value is null or not valid int it won't cause exception, but should be handled anyways.